# How to create an Instance of SuperClass from SubClass?

Tags: c#, oop

Assume there are two types of users in my system, Teachers and Students. Now both teacher and student data is stored in the table Users. Thus I have a class User, which corresponds to the table User.

But then I am creating two classes, Teacher and Student, which inherit from User. Apart from having some extra properties and methods, these classes make the code clearer. (I know more about the Teacher object than the User object. In the default Ctor of Teacher, I am setting fields like UserType to default values for Teacher)

Now I am using the Teacher/Student objects mostly at the api/presentation layer/services layer. But to the Data Access Layer I have to pass a User object as that is what is stored in the Users table. So I need to get a User object from a Teacher/Student object.

I want to avoid writing code to copy each property from Teacher to User and was wondering how do others do this?

Also, is there a better way to design this rather than having separate Teacher/Student classes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If they are derived from User, then it shouldn't matter. You can design your data access to take in a User, and since a Student or a Teacher *is* a User, then it will work just fine.

So given this function declaration:

```
public void SaveUser(User user){
   //Save a user baby!!!
}
```

Then this code is perfectly valid:

```
var myStudent = new Student();
var myTeacher = new Teacher();

SaveUser(myStudent);
SaveUser(myTeacher);
```

Or am I missing something?

Comment: SaveUser asks for a User object, and myStudent and myTeacher both are, so that seems right

Comment: I believe that will throw an InvalidCastException. Because Student and Teacher are derived types, we can cast a User to a Teacher but not vice versa. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469155/why-is-implicit-conversion-allowed-from-superclass-to-subclass

Comment: No it will not throw a cast exception because Student and Teacher **ARE** User objects. There is no need to cast at all. This is precisely the problem that inheritance and polymorphism are designed to solve.

Comment: Ah I just realized that I asked the question the other way. I mean, if I have a method in my DAL which returns a User, I will not be able to cast User to Teacher or Student. So how do I tackle this? Is there a better design?